# Using a 'default' trait in FactoryGirl to avoid unnecessary association creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Is it possible to define a default trait in FactoryGirl? If I define a factory like this (where both question_response belongs_to question):

```
factory :question_response do
  question
  work_history

  trait :open do
    question { FactoryGirl.create :question, question_type: 'open' }
  end
end
```

When I do `FactoryGirl.create :question_response, :open` it will first create a default question and then create another inside the trait, which is an unnecessary operation.

Ideally I'd like to do this:

```
factory :question_response do
  work_history

  trait :default do
    question { FactoryGirl.create :question, question_type: 'yes_no' }
  end

  trait :open do
    question { FactoryGirl.create :question, question_type: 'open' }
  end
end
```

And then doing `FactoryGirl.create :question` will use the default trait, but it doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I do FactoryGirl.create :question_response, :open it will first create a default question and then create another inside the trait

It's not true. if you specify the trait with `question`, it will overwrite the factory behavior before creation so that it does not create a default question.

I checked it with FactoryGirl v4.5.0

Comment: Thanks, you are quite right! I've just verified this myself. I wonder this was added to factory girl recently...

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else is looking for 'default trait' scenario, this was discussed with examples in https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/528#issuecomment-18289143

Basically, you can define trait with defaults and then use it for different factories. And then you can use appropriate factory with needed configuration.

For example:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  trait :user_defaults do
    email { Faker::Internet.unique.email }
    username { Faker::Internet.unique.username }
    password { "test1234" }
  end

  factory :with_admin_role, class: User do
    user_defaults

    after(:create) do |user, _|
      user.add_role :admin
    end
  end

  factory :with_readonly_role, class: User do
    user_defaults

    after(:create) do |user, _|
      user.add_role :readonly
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trait is creating a 2nd record because you have a block that is creating a record:

```
trait :open do
  question { FactoryGirl.create :question, question_type: 'open' }
end
```

Instead, you can do define a trait on question that has the question type set, and then have your question_response use that question with the open trait as its default.

```
factory.define :question do
  trait :open do
    question_type 'open'
  end
end

factory.define :question_response do
  association :question, :open
end
```